# Since when do the Klingons partake in the feasting of this species

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-discovery

> Klingons eat humans now?  ... Although, I guess they might have dined on Michelle Yeoh out of starvation instead of eating her because of some devouring of enemies honor.

So are there ever any other instances of this?  I have not ever heard of this before in canon.

Answer (score 7):

It's been established in prior series that Klingons will sometimes eat the heart of their enemies. In this case, as mentioned, they're short of supplies and stranded. *Humans* will, and have, eaten humans in such situations in real life.

Comment: additionally, they are essentially a cult in many ways, fringe outsiders compared to the other Klingon houses and their ways may simply be different

Comment: Ain't no party like a ***Donner Party***, 'cause a ***Donner Party*** don't stop! ('Til we run out of children...)